# Ignore first item in array in UITableView - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

How can I ignore the first item in an array when display in a TableView?

What I want is to ignore the first item when presented in a UITableView, I DON'T want remove it just not show it in the TableView.

The following code show all items from the array in the TableView.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return lists.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listCell", for: indexPath)

    let data = lists[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = data.listName  
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You're not showing enough code. Show `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: Updated post. Thanks.

Comment: Why not have your master list and also the data model that is actually used by the table view's data source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data source methods are using `lists` as their basis, and you don't want to do anything that mess that up. The `numberOfRowsInSection` and the `cellForRowAt` need to stay in sync.

I can think of two possibilities:

- Keep the *real* model elsewhere, and keep in `lists` only the part of the model that you want to include in the table.
- Or (a whole different approach) implement `heightForRowAt` to give the undesired row a zero height.

Comment: I see, I will go with your first suggestion.

Comment: Good because that's what I would do. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: matt, your exchange with @rmaddy in his deleted answer is hilarious. I went through the same mental process, thought about the "tomfoolery" answer, and decided "Ugh. No."

Comment: It seems to me that the zero height row answer is also nasty and best avoided. Giving the data source a subset of the model is by far the cleanest approach.

Comment: @DuncanC The reason I found it reasonable to mention the zero-height approach is that it's the kind of thing Apple does all the time. For example, that's how they show and hide the date picker when you're editing a date-time in an event in the Calendar app.

Comment: @DuncanC I was originally typing up a full answer about using a 2nd array when Matt's answer appeared. So I removed that and typed the alternative I since deleted. Now I see someone else has posted that same answer.

Comment: @rmaddy And I have duly objected.